# What should be the return type of iter().cloned().filter().map()

Tags: iterator, rust

So I'm returning an iterator in the following way:

```
pub fn get_iter_names(&self) -> ??? {
self.nodes.iter().cloned()
    .filter(|x| x.is_some())
    .map(|x| x.unwrap().name)
}
```

where `self.nodes` is a `Vec<Option<Node>>` and `Node` has a filed `name`. The question is what should be the return type. My compiler says `core::iter::Map<core::iter::Filter<core::iter::Cloned<core::slice::Iter<'_, core::option::Option<core::node::ComputeNode>>>, [closure@src/core/graph.rs:931:12: 931:27]>, [closure@src/core/graph.rs:932:9: 932:28]>`, but the problem is that I do not know how to specify a clousure as a type?

What is the correct way to do this anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure that this question has been asked a lot on Stackoverflow but I can't find any, so here you go.

In Rust unboxed closures have *anonymous* types generated by the compiler. Therefore, there is *no* way to specify them in type signatures. This means that it is impossible to return unboxed closures by value.

The usual solution is to box the return value:

```
pub fn get_iter_names(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=???>> {
    Box::new(self.nodes.iter().cloned()
        .filter(|x| x.is_some())
        .map(|x| x.unwrap().name))
}
```

You should specify whatever type `name` field has instead of `???` (I can't deduce it from your code alone).

There is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105) to allow returning unboxed values implementing some trait but it was postponed. According to the discussion in that RFC PR, it looks like that there is at least some work is done on this recently, so it may be available in Rust (relatively) soon.